# How to Access the MySQL Directory

Tags: html, directory

I was creating a file into my server with this sentence applied in myphpadmin and well of course it creates a file

```
SELECT column1, column2
INTO OUTFILE 'outfile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
FROM table_name;
```

but the file is stored in var/lib/mysql

How can I access that directory VAR/LIB/MYSQL from the brother just like we access the domain after the www directory?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "access .. from the brother"? Which brother?

Comment: *"from the brother"* What?

Comment: I think it means "from the browser"

Comment: Yes it was the browser .. LOL ... hope you still alive to read this ! :) best wishes this 2024

Answer (score 2):

`var/lib/mysql` is a local directory that does not have external (www) access. If you're using phpMyAdmin, you should use the export feature.